# How can I alert the user if a new line is inserted in the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a desktop application inserting values into a mysql table with fields `id`, `keyword` and `timestamp`

I have a php page which is kept open in my browser and lists all entries from that database.

What I want to do is to have this page automatically check if there's a new entry in the database and warn me. This warning must be a sound.

I consider an entry to be new if it's timestamp is less than 60 seconds the current timestamp.

So, I have the mysql query which does check for new entries, but my main question is, how to perform that query every 1 second without manually refreshing the page? And how to play a sound alarm when a new entry is found?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to do it:

Within the page's `<head>` node, the following code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('#divToRefresh').load('dbcheck.php');
}, 500); // refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
});
// ]]></script>
```

Then, somewhere in the page:

```
<div id="divToRefresh">Running...</div>
```

And naturally, I've created a new php file called dbcheck.php containing which connects to the database and contains the following:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT keyword, timestamp FROM keywords ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
$query3 = $pdo->prepare($sql3);
$query3->execute();
$result3 = $query3->fetch();

$timestampCheck = time() - 120;
if ($result3['timestamp'] >= $timestampCheck)
{
echo "<div>NEW KEYWORD FOUND!</div>\n\n";
echo "<div>", $result3['keyword'], "</div>";

echo "<audio autoplay=\"autoplay\">
<source src=\"alarm.wav\" type=\"audio/wav\">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>";

}
else
{
echo "Listening...";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try using ajax get function with setTimeout to run indefinitly:

```
function checkDB()
{
    $.get("checkDB.php","",function(data) {
        if(data=="1") //if new entry is present
        {
            //use sound manager to play a sound file
        }
    });
    setTimeout("checkDB()",1000); // this will ensure this function to run every 1000 milliseconds
}
```

[sound manager link](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)

Comment: I get "Call to undefined function setTimeout()".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into WebSockets or Long Polling. [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet) is a good post that goes into some detail about the options you have. [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743388/long-polling-message-system) is a post that might be able to help with Long Polling.

Answer (score 0):

U can use ajax for this and persistent connection to be faster as it leave the connection open